# Trying to get the url value from twitter's search results

Tags: javascript, twitter, getjson

I am trying to getthe url from twitter's search results but am getting undefined in the array.
Does anyone know why am not getting the url ?

```
    function get(){
    var array=[];
        $.getJSON("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=euronews&rpp=5&
        include_entities=true&result_type=mixed&callback=?",
      function(data){
   $.each(data.results, function(i, item){
      var user=item.from_user;
      var user_id=item.from_user_id;
      var date=item.created_at;
      var profile_img=item.profile_image_url;
      var url=item.entities.urls[0].url;
    create_array(user,user_id,date,profile_img,url);
     });

    function create_array(a,b,c,d,e){
         array.push({user:a,user_id:b,date:c,profile_img:d,url:e});

                    }console.log(array);
}); 
}
```

This the structure of the json file i get from twitter search results:
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=euronews&rpp=5&include_entities=true&result_type=mixed

cheers :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting `undefined` is because item.entities.urls is an array. It turns out that not all results have an array either. This should work for you:

```
var array = [];

$.getJSON("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=euronews&rpp=5&include_entities=true&result_type=mixed&callback=?",
    function(data){
        $.each(data.results, function(i, item){
            array.push({
                user: item.from_user,
                user_id: item.from_user_id,
                date: item.created_at,
                profile_img: item.profile_image_url,
                url: (item.entities.urls.length > 0 ? item.entities.urls[0].url : '')
            });
        });
        console.log(array);
    }
);
```

Comment: There is only one value in the array, so item.entities.urls[1] will be undefined. Post your code in an edit to the main question so I can see what you're doing.

Comment: I have to put the code on the above comment.Can you see it?It says Thanks for your edit!
This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed.

Comment: @anjelos -- Rejected your edit; add that code to your question as White Elephant suggests.

Comment: TypeError: item.entities.urls[0] is undefined

Comment: i already did that and it says it has to reviewed first and the u can view it

Comment: No anjelos. @Ben rejected your edit correctly. You have to edit your **question**.

Comment: TypeError: item.entities is undefined
[Break On This Error]  

var url=(item.entities.urls.length > 0 ? item.entities.urls[0].url : '');

Comment: it works now @WhiteElephant ,but can u explain to me what this (item.entities.urls.length > 0 ? item.entities.urls[0].url : '') does?